# Gráfico a tiempo real con puerto serie y matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyserial

Estoy intentando graficar en tiempo real los datos que vienen desde el puerto serie. Para ello estoy haciendo pruebas con "Advanced Serial Port Terminal" para enviar datos desde el puerto COM1 al COM2, con un bucle que se repite cada 500 ms:

[image: Advanced Serial Port Terminal]

Para leer los datos hasta el momento no tengo inconveniente, ya que los puedo imprimir en la consola:

[image: Consola]

y el código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
import serial
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import threading
import numpy as np
import collections

gData = collections.deque([0]*10, maxlen=10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.xlim(0,10)
ax = plt.axes()
hl = ax.plot([], [])[0]

def getData(out_data):
    with serial.Serial('COM2',9600, timeout=0) as ser:
        while True:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
            try:
                out_data.append(float(line))
            except:
                pass

            print(out_data)
            time.sleep(0.5)

dataCollector = threading.Thread(target= getData, args = (gData,))
dataCollector.start()

def update_line(num, hl, data):
    dx = np.array(range(0,len(data)))
    dy = np.array(data)
    hl.set_data(dx, dy)
    return hl,

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, fargs = (hl, gData), interval=500)

plt.show()

dataCollector.join()
```

La idea es que la actualización del array que almacena los datos se esté actualizando en un hilo separado , encargado de leer los datos que llegan al puerto COM2.

Si bien puedo leer los datos e imprimirlos, no logro que se visualicen en la figura, y la misma queda:

[image: Figura]

Por lo que entiendo yo, la función de animación (`update_line`) del plot  se llama cada 500 ms, y se ejecuta en un hilo separado. No entiendo bien cual es problema ya que según la documentación que leí sobre las animaciones de `matplotlib.animation`, `FuncAnimation()` recibe como parámetros la figura que se desea actualizar, la función que realiza la actualización, los argumentos que recibe esta función de actualización y el intervalo de refresco entre otros parámentros.

Desde ya muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Ummm estoy ya algo espeso hoy, no caigo en que puede estar pasando... Acabo de probar tu código en Linux, emulando un puerto con socat y un script Python generando datos aleatorios y todo parece funcionar como debe... :(

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, puedo esperar para una respuesta.

Comment: No tengo acceso a una máquina con Windows ahora en la que hacer pruebas y en Linux yo al menos no puedo reproducir el problema como comentaba arriba, funciona perfectamene. Una observación si haría, deque es thread safe para append y len, pero la iteración es por definición una operación no atómica. Cuando creas el array con numpy se debe iterar sobre la cola y nada asegura que mientras tanto el hilo no modifique la cola. Yo usaría un candado para evitar posibles condiciones de carrera.

Comment: El cálculo de dx (que es siempre el mismo array) lo sacaría de la función para evitar la sobrecarga innecesaria. No obstante lo anterior no debería tener nada que ver con el bloqueo de la ventana de matplotlib si no hay excepciones de por medio. Es más, se puede leer del puerto directamente en update_line mientras la lectura no sea bloqueante sin problemas sin necesidad de un hilo. El bloqueo que muestras es típico cuando la función llamada por FuncAnimation() (update_line) es bloqueante y tarda mucho en retornar, pero no es el caso...

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He probado leer los datos del puerto desde la misma función de actualización (update_line) y funciona !!. Pero ahora me surge otro problema, en realidad estoy haciendo pruebas para graficar datos en tres gráficos simultáneamente, por lo tanto tengo tres funciones de actualización. Si leo los datos del puerto en cada función (digamos update_line, update_line2, update_line3) solo me grafica los datos en una sola figura. Por ejemplo comienza dibujando en la figura 1. Si cierro la figura 1 me empieza a dibujar en la figura 2, y si cierro la figura 2 me dibuja en la 3.

Comment: He probado de usar solo una función de actualización para las tres figuras, pero no me funciona de la manera que yo esperaba, es como que los datos aparecen distorsionados. Probablemente no lo esté implementando de la forma correcta.

Comment: Ahora que veo, eres el mismo usuario que me respondió una pregunta de otra publicación hace unos días para graficar tres gráficos en tiempo real con una interfaz de usuario con tkinter. Justamente estaba haciendo estas pruebas para leer los datos del puerto y actualizar esos gráficos. Te vuelvo a agradecer por tu gran ayuda. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, hoy acabo de probar en Windows 10 con un puerto virtual y tampoco tengo ningún problema con tu código... La grafica se muestra y actualiza sin problemas... En cuanto a usar solo una función, si no te importa tener una sola figura con tres subplots uno para cada gráfico, puedes animar los tres ejes sin problemas desde la misma callback. Solo que la función que ahora retorna solo hl, debe retornar todos los Artits necesarios.